# Scoring Logistic Regression Model Code in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm quite new to Spark and I have some logistic regression model score code built in another language that I'm converting to run in Spark. This model code resides in a text file. Below is a sample of the model code...

```
score = 0.27491575973075
+ (residence ='7' )*-0.17704835393105
+ (residence ='8' )*-0.17704835393105
+ (state =9 )*0.64242832288369
+ (state =1 )*-0.15066703353302
+ (state =2 )*-0.12015049320814
+ (state =8 )*-0.12015049320814
;
prob=score/(1+e^score);
```

The above has an intercept of 0.27491575973075 and increments/decrements the value based on whether or not the column for that row is the value labeled. Once the statement has finished, this goes through the logit transformation to receive a probability score (prob).

i.e. + (residence ='7' )*-0.17704835393105 does an if check to see if residence is equal to 7, if so then that row will be +(1)*-0.17704835393105 --> + (-0.17704835393105)

I'm trying to implement something similar to this in Spark. Each column has other values than the ones listed in the excerpt above. 
i.e. residence has values 1-9 and state can have values 1-52.

Is there a way I can do something similar with if statements scattered in this linear formula?